# Akeneo error with statuses and bulk actions

Tags: akeneo

There is an issue in Akeneo. When i try to do a bulk action an change the status of multiple products the bulk action fails with below error:

```
{"ERROR":
    {
        "ROOT_CAUSE":[
            {"TYPE":"CLUSTER_BLOCK_EXCEPTION","REASON":"BLOCKED BY: [FORBIDDEN/12/INDEX READ-ONLY / ALLOW DELETE (API)];"}
        ],
        "TYPE":"CLUSTER_BLOCK_EXCEPTION","REASON":"BLOCKED BY: [FORBIDDEN/12/INDEX READ-ONLY / ALLOW DELETE (API)];"
    },
    "STATUS":403
}
```

When I try to change the status manually for a single product it throws an error.

```
Server error. Error! Incorrect server response.
```

When I look in developers console I see the following url `/enrich/product/881/toggle-status` with below error

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
```

The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Undoubtedly both isues are related. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with diskspace. Elastic Search switches to read only mode when it reaches a treshold. The solution was to run below command.

`curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'`

Source: https://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2017/12/23/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api-read-only-elasticsearch-indices/